# Let $m<n$. Why is $\mathbb R^m$ closed in $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $m<n$. Why $\mathbb R^m$ is closed in $\mathbb R^n$ ? For example, let us take $\mathbb R^3$ and the subspace $\mathbb R^2$. It looks weird to me that $\mathbb R^2$ is closed in $\mathbb R^3$. To me it looks impossible. It may be open, but not closed. Any explanation is welcome.

Comment: Do you know the definitions of open/closed?

Comment: As the inverse image of the closed set $\{0\}$ by the continuous function $x\mapsto x_{m+1}^2+\cdots x_n^2$, perhaps?

Comment: @Did Elegant solution. "..., perhaps?" can be missed or replaced by "...!".

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbf R^m$ is a finite intersection of hyperplanes in $\mathbf R^n$. Each of these is closed, as it's the kernel of a (continuous) linear form.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\boldsymbol  x=(x,y,0)\in\mathbb R^2$. We denote $$B(\boldsymbol x,\varepsilon)=\{\boldsymbol u\in \mathbb R^3\mid \|\boldsymbol x-\boldsymbol u\|\leq \varepsilon\}.$$

I think it's very easy to show (even to see), that for all $\varepsilon>0$, $$B(\boldsymbol x,\varepsilon)\cap \mathbb R^2\neq \emptyset\quad \text{and}\quad B(\boldsymbol x,\varepsilon)\cap (\mathbb R^2)^c\neq \emptyset.$$
In particular, $\mathbb R^2\subset \partial \mathbb R^3.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $V$ be any plane in ${\mathbb R}^3$, e.g., the $(x_1,x_2)$-plane $x_3=0$. If ${\bf p}\notin V$ then we can drop a normal $n$ from ${\bf p}$ to $V$, which then will hit $V$ at some point ${\bf p}'$. Note that all points ${\bf x}\in V$ satisfy $$|{\bf x}-{\bf p}|\geq|{\bf p}'-{\bf p}|=:d>0\ .$$ It follows that the ball with radius ${d\over2}$ and center ${\bf p}$ does not intersect $V$. Since ${\bf p}\notin V$ was arbitrary we thus have proven that the complement ${\mathbb R}^3\setminus V$ is open, hence $V$ is closed in ${\mathbb R}^3$.